# Apply the second partials test to $f$ at $(0, 0)$. For which values of $k$ is the test inconclusive

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This is what i done, not entirely sure it is correct.
first found the derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ it was $2x+ky$
then found the derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to y it was $2y+kx$
i then let both of them equal $0$

solved $2x+ky=0$ looking for a value of x and i got $x=-ky/2$
i then put this value for x back into $2y+kx=0$  i got y to cancel and i got a value for k. i got $k=2$.

so then i rewrote my derivatives as $2x+2y=0$
and $2y+2x=0$
went ahead and tried to solve one of them for a value of x so i could sub it back
and i got $x=-y$
then i went and subbed this new value for x back into the equation and i'm getting $0=0$
This means that for k=2 the test is inclusive correct?
considering the question is stating "values" meaning plural? how would find more values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to solve for $x,y$ since the critical point is already given. Plugging $(0,0)$ into first partials of $f$. If they are both evaluated $0$, then this verifies $(0,0)$ is a critical point.

Now you need to find the Hessian matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}&\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}&\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) for the second derivative test by Hessain matrix.